# Canvas not loading using FXML

Tags: java, javafx, canvas, fxml

I have to use the canvas to draw a curve inside my application, but I think my FXML is not loading the Canvas properly.
This is how I initialize it:

```java
    @FXML
    private Canvas canvas;
    private GraphicsContext gc;

    @FXML
    private LineChart<String, Number> chart1;


    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        canvas = new Canvas(1000, 1000);
        gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setStroke(Color.RED);
        gc.setLineWidth(10);

        canvas.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            gc.beginPath();
            gc.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            gc.stroke();
        });

        canvas.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            gc.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            gc.stroke();
        });
    }
}
```

And in FXML:

```
<ScrollPane>
      <content>
            <Canvas fx:id="canvas" height="298.0" width="455.0" />
      </content>
</ScrollPane>
```

This is an example of how it looks now: [image]
That blue border should be a canvas.

When I comment out the Canvas part from FXML, nothing changes, so that tells me it does not work. What might be wrong?

Comment: You are overwriting the original canvas object with canvas = new Canvas(1000, 1000); -- remove that and see if it works. Annotating the field with @FXML initializes it for you

Comment: Just a clarification: In order to draw a curve you do not necessarily have to use a Canvas. That is just one of the possible options. Another one would be to just add a Path object to the scenegraph.

Comment: That worked! Thanks @Joe

Comment: Ok I did not know that, thanks for the info @mipa